# Package.json showing differant version of react

Tags: reactjs

I am developing teams application using react js. Package.Json file showing version as 16.14.0.
But when I am getting the react version from terminal window its showing 17.0.2. Is that shows my application has 2 versions of react?

Here below is the screenshot of `package.json` file
[image]

Comment: Can you share screenshot?

Comment: Not able to upload image. Not allowing me to upload image...

Comment: Thats not possible

Comment: Hi Harry, Uploaded screenshots for your reference

Comment: I have edited the question, and the screenshot is appearing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you have installed React JS globally as well on your OS. This way you have two versions of React JS, One for your project and another one for your global environment.

Although there is a way to know the runtime version of React in the browser.

```js
const REACT_VERSION = React.version;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>React version: {REACT_VERSION}</div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

In case, if you want to check React imported as a module, then go with the following code snippet.

```
import React from 'react';

console.log(React.version);
```

Comment: I am trying to use "ag grid react" dependency for creating table structure - When running the application its throwing "Invalid hook call" error message. I checked some of the links and they said it may be due to duplicate version of react. Do you think this error message is throwing beacuse of these 2 versions of react? If yes how can I solve this duplicate version of react

Comment: can you remove node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and install all the modules again in the application project folder?

Comment: Deleting the node_modules folder solved my issue.. Thank you for your support